# Retrieving table with @ElementCollection in hibernate through spring mvc results in multiple instances of the table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I have created a table with @ElementCollection like

Table name is Job

```
 @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 @CollectionTable(name="JobSkills", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="job_Id"))
 @GenericGenerator(name= "hilo-gen" ,strategy = "hilo")
 @CollectionId(columns= { @Column(name= "jobSkillId") }, generator= "hilo-gen",    type= @Type(type="long"))
 Collection<JobSkill> jobSkill = new ArrayList<JobSkill>();
```

the other table is

```
@Embeddable
public class JobSkill {
     String skill;
//getter setters
}
```

The problem is when i fetch the table Job in controller and display it in jsp Job table appears as many times as it got skills. If i enter 3 skills it appears 3 times.

My controller method is

```
@RequestMapping(value= "getalljobs")
public String getAllJobsForm(Model model){

    List<Job> allJobs = companyService.getallPostedJobs(getCmpName());
    model.addAttribute("allJobs", allJobs);
    model.addAttribute("companyname",getCmpName());

    return "alljobs";
}
```

fetching list of Job table and my Jsp page is

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <c:forEach items="${allJobs }" var="job">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h5>Job id : ${job.jobId }</h5>
                        <h5>Job Title : ${job.jobTitle }</h5>
                        <h5>Job Location : ${job.jobLocation }</h5>
                        <h5>expRequired : ${job.expRequired }</h5>
                        <h5>higestQualification : ${job.higestQualification }</h5>
                        <h5>jobDescription : ${job.jobDescription }</h5>
                        <h5>overAllPerReq : ${job.overAllPerReq }</h5>
                        <h5>salaryMin : ${job.salaryMin }</h5>
                        <c:forEach items="${job.jobSkill }" var="skills">
                            <h3>Skill : ${skills.skill }</h3>
                        </c:forEach>

                        <a href="<spring:url value='/company/deletejob?id=${job.jobId }' />" class="btn btn-warning">Delete</a>                         
                        <a href="<spring:url value='/students/edit?id=${job.jobId }' />" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
```

In jsp page the job table is listed three time with same id(primary key).

What have i done wrong. Will post more code if needed to understand the problem.

To understand problem better I have sysout in controller. The output is

```
@RequestMapping(value= "getalljobs")
public String getAllJobsForm(Model model){


    List<Job> allJobs = companyService.getallPostedJobs(getCmpName());
    model.addAttribute("allJobs", allJobs);
    model.addAttribute("companyname",getCmpName());


    System.out.println("----------------");
    for(Job job: allJobs){
        System.out.println(job.getJobId());
        for(JobSkill skill: job.getJobSkill()){
            System.out.println(skill.getSkill());
        }
    }

    return "alljobs";       
}
```

output

```
1
java
php
sql

1
java
php
sql

1
java
php 
sql
```

It repeats 3 times cause i entered 3 skills. The 1 in output is jobId.

Comment: Can you tell if the allJobs has the same result as in UI ?

Comment: I didn't get into the second part of the question at all, but the first problem I see is the wrong mapping. For `@ElementCollectoin` you should use `@CollectionTable` insead of `@JoinTable`. And, do you really need `@CollectionId`?

Comment: I changed it to @CollectionTable, but the problem is still the same. Repetition of table.

Comment: @Gaurav i have added the output in question

Comment: Changing the mapping from List to Set solved problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the mapping from List to Set solved the problem.